# How to target a deeply nested header element

Tags: css, sass

I have a h3 tag which is deeply nested as follows and can't amend the component that contains

this styling.

Instead since I only have 1 h3 within this nest, trying to target it and amend its padding.

But this is not working. Can I know what I am doing wrong? I am doing something similar for another

div tag targeting the 6th position for that div. That works fine. Issue is with targetting this h3
tag. Tried adding !important to these styling which makes no diff. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the structure of the html currently.

```
// This is the only div I created passing in my custom styling and the component is wrapped within this. 
<div className={styles.main}>
    // all the following is coming from an external component I can't amend. 
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>some span text 1</span>
                    <div>some span text 2</div> <!-- also targetting this div and this works fine. See CSS below --> 
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3> <!-- This is the only h3 in entire nest -->
                        Some Random Text <!-- trying to give this a left padding --> 
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My SCSS File

```
.main > div:nth-child(5) {
    padding-top: 100px; // this works fine 
} 

// tried all the following. None of them works. I do not get the padding left 50px; 
// The text is stuck to the left with no margin / padding.  

.main > h3 {
    padding-left: 50px !important; // Don't want to use !important. Tried with it just in case it works. 
}

.main > h3:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 50px !important; // Don't want to use !important. Tried with it just in case it works. 
}

.main > h3:first-child {
    padding-left: 50px !important; // Don't want to use !important. Tried with it just in case it works. 
}
```

Comment: If this is the only `h3` in the nest them `.main h3` should suffice.

Comment: If it’s the only `h3` then just target it with `h3` Only.

Comment: `@at-root` Is another option. ```.main {
    @at-root h3 {
  padding-left: 100px;
  }
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the direct descendant selector.

You are only selecting `h3` elements that are direct children of `.main`

You need to modify your selector to select children/grandchildren/etc.

```css
.main h3 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Double checked again and this is the only h3 tag within this block. Targeting it as suggested doesnt work.

Comment: Can you double check that the class is main?

Comment: Yes, the class is main.

Comment: you have `classname={styles.main}` use `class="main"` in your html and access it like @DanMullin answer suggests